# Respond to popScene

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am using pushScene and popScene in my cocos2d-iphone game (1.0.1).

So I have this:

Scene1, Scene2 (Scene2 being the pushed scene).

Now I use popScene, so I have

Scene1.

Is there a way to run a method in Scene1 when it is recovered from the popScene method? I mean, I want Scene1 to realize that it is back to work. I tried putting something in the onEnter method, but really didn't work (either the screen was black or the touches didn't work)

Comment: You should be able to do it on either the onEnter or onEnterTransitionDidFinish methods. Can you share a bit more information? Like the onEnter code or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, fixed.

You can indeed use the onEnter method, but you have to call `[super onEnter]` first.

I was doing this:

```
-(void)onEnter {
      [self doSomething];
}
```

But it should have been like this:

```
-(void)onEnter {
      [super onEnter];
      [self doSomething];
}
```